# Performance: saving data in a small file vs in a fixed-size header section of a large file

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, io, filesystems

Are there any performance differences between writing a small (1000 bytes) amount of text data to a new file, compared to opening a large file with `mode='r+'` option, seeking to the start, and writing the same text there?

Use case: I need to read and write a small amount (~1000 bytes) of text meta data for larger (1 MB+) text files. The meta data is accessed much more often than the large files. At present, the meta data is stored in separate files.

I was thinking to store the meta data in the header of the large file instead; in other words, pad the meta data to some fixed size (say, 4096 bytes), and read/write the meta data to the fixed-size section at the beginning of the large file.

Note: I understand that padding a Python 3 string to a fixed size in bytes is slightly non-trivial, but since the space character is exactly one byte in UTF-8, I can make it work.